# How to continuously active Internet on doze mode Marshmallow and Nougat

Tags: android, android-service

I'm working on real-time location tracking app and updating current location to the server via using foreground service. 
Now i'm able to keep app active while device in deep sleep. But due to Network access is suspended on Doze mode, i can't able to update it on server.
As per google developer guide suggestion we can solve this issue by using high-priority FCM messages.
But in my case how to notify server for push notification while Network access is suspended (need to identify internet access disable either by OS or manually).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, but still i'm searching proper alternate solutions.

Comment: If you find, please make me alert. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I can do this on M and N using GcmTaskService. Although, this no longer works for O

Answer (score 2):

One way is register for action-

```
"android.os.action.DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED"
```

this will broadcast once the device modes will change and then figure out device is in doze/non-doze using :

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

boolean isDeviceIdle = pm.isDeviceIdleMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check NetworkInfo status

```
public static boolean isNetBlocked(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState().name().equals(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.BLOCKED.name());
}
```

Comment: It returns `Blocked` when device is _Battery on saver_ and _Restrict background data_ modes

Comment: when internet is disabled by OS or manually, then in both condition "networkInfo" return null.